# Python - How to iterate through a dataframe and replace a value in one cell with a value from another in the same row

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to create a new column in a dataframe of food ingredients with unique values per row based on information from other cells in the same row.

The table essentially looks like this:

```
ingredient_name | ingredient_method | consolidated_name
Cheese          | [camembert, pkg]  | 
Cheese          | [cream, pastueri] |
Egg             | [raw, scrambled]  |
```

I'm trying to iterate through the rows and fill the `consolidated_name` column with values from either `ingredient_name` or `ingredient_method`.
For example, if `ingredient_name` is "Cheese" I want that row's consolidated name to be the first element of the list in `ingredient_method`.

This is the code I have so far:

```
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    consolidated = df['ingredient_name']
    if (df['ingredient_name'] == 'Cheese').all():
        consolidated = df['ingredient_method'][0]
    df.set_value(i,'consolidated_name',consolidated)
```

The code runs without errors but none of the values change in the dataframe.
Any ideas?

Comment: Can you add expected output? What happens in last row?

Comment: You are not using the `i`'s and `row`'s in your code. Further, it seems like `set_value` method is not an in-place operation so your `df` will not change at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`DataFrame.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html#pandas.DataFrame.apply) for that purpose. Simply wrap your decision logic (which is now in the `for` loop) into a corresponding function.

```
def func(row):
    if row['ingredient_name'] == 'Cheese':
        return row['ingredient_method'][0]
    return None

df['consolidated_name'] = df.apply(func, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 2):

One could use `.loc` (combined to `.str[0]`)

With:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(ingredient_name=['Cheese','Cheese','Egg'],
                  ingredient_method=[['camembert', 'pkg'],
                                     ['cream', 'pastueri'],
                                     ['raw', 'scrambled']]))
```

Do:

```
#Initialize consolidated_name with None for instance
df['consolidated_name'] = [None]*len(df) #Not mandatory, will fill with NaN if not set

#Use .loc to get the rows you want and .str[0] to get the first elements
_filter = df.ingredient_name=='Cheese' #Filter you want to
df.loc[_filter,'consolidated_name'] = df.loc[_filter,'ingredient_method'].str[0]
```

Result:

```
print(df)
   ingredient_method ingredient_name consolidated_name
0   [camembert, pkg]          Cheese         camembert
1  [cream, pastueri]          Cheese             cream
2   [raw, scrambled]             Egg              None
```

---

**Note**

**#1**
If you want to consolidate all the duplicated ingredients you can filter with the following:

```
_duplicated = df.ingredient_name[df.ingredient_name.duplicated()]
_filter = df.ingredient_name.isin(_duplicated)
```

The use of `.loc` is unchanged see next example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(ingredient_name=['Cheese','Cheese','Egg','Foo','Foo'],
                  ingredient_method=[['camembert', 'pkg'], 
                                     ['cream', 'pastueri'], 
                                     ['raw', 'scrambled'], 
                                     ['bar', 'taz'], 
                                     ['taz', 'bar']]))

_duplicated = df.ingredient_name[df.ingredient_name.duplicated()]
_filter = df.ingredient_name.isin(_duplicated)
df.loc[_filter,'consolidated_name'] = df.loc[_filter,'ingredient_method'].str[0]
print(df)

   ingredient_method ingredient_name consolidated_name
0   [camembert, pkg]          Cheese         camembert
1  [cream, pastueri]          Cheese             cream
2   [raw, scrambled]             Egg               NaN
3         [bar, taz]             Foo               bar
4         [taz, bar]             Foo               taz
```

**#2**
If you want you can initialize with `ingredient_name`:

```
df['consolidated_name'] = df.ingredient_name
```

Then do your stuff:

```
_duplicated = df.ingredient_name[df.ingredient_name.duplicated()]
_filter = df.ingredient_name.isin(_duplicated)
df.loc[_filter,'consolidated_name'] = df.loc[_filter,'ingredient_method'].str[0]
print(df)

   ingredient_method ingredient_name consolidated_name
0   [camembert, pkg]          Cheese         camembert
1  [cream, pastueri]          Cheese             cream
2   [raw, scrambled]             Egg               Egg #Here it has changed
3         [bar, taz]             Foo               bar
4         [taz, bar]             Foo               taz
```

Comment: Maybe `df['consolidated_name'] = [None]*len(df)` should be omit.

Comment: Yes, it fills with `NaN` instead. (Updated my answer)

Comment: Thanks David — this worked but I'm accepting the answer below because the for loop framework lets me set logic for multiple ingredients beyond cheese. The framework you shared seems to only let me do one filter at a time unless I'm missing something?

Comment: Maybe you could provide such example to see if it fits? (In my opinion it should)

Answer (score 0):

If you want do it using your initial loop.

```
consolidated_name = []
for i,row in df.iterrows():
    if row[0] =='Cheese':
        consolidated_name.append(row[1][0])
    else: consolidated_name.append(None)

df['consolidated_name']=consolidated_name

## out:
  ingredient_name  ingredient_method consolidated_name
0          Cheese   [camembert, pkg]         camembert
1          Cheese  [cream, pastueri]             cream
2             Egg   [raw, scrambled]              None
```